# What does it mean by Framework agnostic?

Tags: frameworks, web-component, micro-frontend

I am hearing this phrase for a long time. I read few articles also still I am not able to understand what does it actually mean. I always see they give some framework name. But I want to understand what it means and why it came. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 20):

Framework agnostic in general means exactly that i.e. agnostic or independent of any framework.

Since you have not mentioned the context here I assume that you want to know about it from the point of view of JavaScript and front-end web development.

To give you an example, companies or product teams often deal with the following priorities

- Often in large companies, there are multiple teams working on various modules or sections of the front end of their product. These teams are often autonomous and self-steering meaning they choose their own Javascript framework to do front-end development.
- However, being a company you would want to make sure the user experience is the same across all the different modules and sections of your product irrespective of what each team chooses to work with.

In order to balance these two competing priorities, the concept of framework-agnostic web component libraries comes in handy. To make it work as a company you encourage your team to develop a library of web components that are independent of any framework such as Vue, Angular, and React. The teams can then use these components interchangeably no matter what framework they use.

Here are some links that should help

- https://dev.to/stefannieuwenhuis/3-reasons-why-i-went-framework-agnostic-and-why-you-should-do-that-too-2o37
- https://micro-frontends.org/#the-dom-is-the-api
- https://j11y.io/javascript/a-framework-agnostic-model/

Comment: very helpful answer, just a tiny correction "you encourage **your** team to.." instead of "you encourage **you** team to".. it was showing me "edit queue is full.. ", Thanks

Answer (score 5):

xyz is 'Framework agnostic' simply means that xyz does not depend on any framework. It is a great and much required idea that focuses on building libraries/components which are not dependent on any specific framework for their implementation, rather to develop a generic stuff to cater everyone.

Here is a brilliant article to know more about the core idea behind it.
https://micro-frontends.org/#the-dom-is-the-api

Comment: Precisely! Well Said!